# Log Moment Generating function of a two-state Markov source

Tags: calculus, probability, matrices, markov-chains

Let's say you have a two-state markovian source whose transition matrix is $P=\begin{pmatrix}1-\sigma & \sigma\\ \tau & 1-\tau\end{pmatrix}$, for the state 0 the data rate is 0 and for the state 1 the data rate is R.

Then at any time (discrete) the amount of incoming data $B_k$ is $B_k = \left\{\begin{matrix} 0, p^0_k
\\ 
R,p^1_k
\end{matrix}\right.$, where the $p_k$ can be computed as such:

Let's say that you have a 0.5 probability of starting with each state. Then the probability that at the time $k$ you are in the state $i, i \in \begin{Bmatrix}0,1\end{Bmatrix}$ is the $i^{th}$ value of the vector $\begin{pmatrix}\frac 1 2\\ \frac 1 2\end{pmatrix}\cdot P^k$
I manage to get an expression of $P^k$ by using an eigendecomposition. You can have the result [here (wolfram)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1-sigma%2C+sigma%7D%2C+%7Btau%2C+1-tau%7D%7D%5En)

Then I need to get the log moment generating function of such a source. This is defined by:
$$
\Gamma(\theta) = \lim_{n\to\infty} ({ \frac 1 n \times ln(E(e^{\theta \times A_n}))})
$$
With $E$ being the expectation of a random variable, and $A_n$ being the the total arrival, so $\sum_{k=1}^{n} B_k$

That's where I have some trouble.

Can I transform the expectation the product into a product of expectation?

Any advice?

Thank you

Here is the result, if can help:

$\Gamma(\theta)=ln(\frac 1 2 *[(1-\tau)e^{\theta R}+(1-\sigma)+\sqrt{(1-\tau)e^{\theta R}+(1-\sigma)^2-4e^{\theta R}(1-\tau-\sigma)}])$

Comment: From this expression, I think I can transform the expectation of the product into a product of expectation. Is it right? I don't wether it will bring me somewhere or not. Also I do have the answer, but I am asked to prove it.